# Android simple voice capture button, NullPointerException

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception, audio-recording

I'm trying to make my self a simple rec button for capture audio from user.
I find the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) and i'm trying to change something but an error occurs and i don't know what is the problem.

Logcat error:

```
12-03 18:43:21.773  11093-11093/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ddz.diarioscolastico/com.ddz.diarioscolastico.ActivityRegistrazione}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ddz.diarioscolastico.ActivityRegistrazione.onCreate(ActivityRegistrazione.java:114)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at
```

And there is my changed code

```
public class ActivityRegistrazione extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    //private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    //private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    /*class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }*/

    public ActivityRegistrazione() {
        //mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/diarioscolastico");
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/diarioscolastico";


        boolean success = true;
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            success = mFolder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success) {

            // Create an audio file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String audioFileName = "AUDIO_" + timeStamp + "_.3gp";
            // Do something on success
            mFileName += "/"+ audioFileName ;

        } else {
            // Do something else on failure
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        final Button recButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
        recButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                boolean mStartRecording = true;

                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    recButton.setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    recButton.setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_registrazione, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The problem is that the example use a button created from java, but i need a static button from xml, so i try to generate it and search it with the id but when i launch the activity the app crash and the error is in the logcat.

Some ideas??

Comment: can you show me what is at this line?
ActivityRegistrazione.java line 114

because according to the error log, it occurs there. and post your xml file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you miss a line on onCreate handler.

After calling super.onCreate(...) and before search for the views, you should set the content, something like this:

```
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
final Button recButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
```

where mylayout is the layout name associated with this view and containing the recButton.